# How do I add multiple members to a board at once

Tags: trello-boards

I would like to invite 100+ members to view a board (not the organisation as there are boards associated with the organisation I do not want them to see) without having to manually enter 100+ email addresses - is very time consuming.

The organisation has a handful of members and I would like to leave it at that, so this is only related to a particular board.

Any help would be great, as I'll give yup using Trello if I have to do this manually.

Thasnk.